# Heterogenous Data Sources

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've got some data that has regular variables as well as text.  Something like the following...

```
Gene    Variation   Class   Text
FAM58A  Truncating  1   Cyclin-dependent kinases (CDKs) regulate a variety of fundamental cellular processes....
```

The `Text` field is quite verbose, often a few paragraphs.  I'd like to perform some tokenization to eventually do machine learning with, but I'm not sure how to include the `Gene` and `Variation` variables (which are categorical) into the design matrix.

Simply slapping them on to the ends of my term document matrix may work, but I am confident there are other ways to go about this (perhaps training two classifiers, one for the text and the other for the categorical variables, and then having a weighted vote).

What other approaches do I have with sklearn for heterogenous data?

Comment: Probably you should translate your text into data with fixed column size then add another categorial columns to the data. You can transform categories into numbers and try different models (linear, random forest, etc.).  For example, use sklearn.feature_extraction to get sparse matrix, then reduce number of features, then make your classifier on the result data.

Comment: Probably you can make 2 intermediate classifiers and then one result classifier which predicts looking to results of the 2 classifiers, but probably such model could be worse because you lost most of the input information.